# IS there a way to extract SCALA Source code from JAR?

Tags: scala, jar, decompiling, decompiler

Tried converting the JAR to zip, javap and scalac does not help me.

been trying to decompile a JAR for a while now, but the SCALA Class files gets converted to java which does not make any sense. Appreciate a quick breakthrough in this. Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35737441/extract-scala-source-code-from-jar

Comment: Decompilation is offered natively by the compiler as of Scala 3, currently under development with the name Dotty. I've added this as an answer to the question linked in the comment above. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63884490/3314107